# REST assured: Wait for a condition before running all tests

Tags: java, api, testing, junit, rest-assured

I have a service that when it's being loaded, it takes a while (few minutes) until all the information is getting into the database.

If I run the tests prematurely, they will fail for that reason (missing items in DB).

Is there some REST assured feature to deal with it? Or I need to have my own mechanism to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest-Assured cannot decide if the service has started unless the service itself provides the endpoint to check its status. Moreover Rest-Assured does not manage test life-cycle.

But JUnit does. You can achieve what you need by coding the condition logic in `@BeforeAll` and `@BeforeEach` methods like this:

```java
boolean serviceStarted = false;

@BeforeAll
public void waitForServiceStart(){
    try{
        // Wait for conditions here
        serviceStarted = true;
    }catch (Throwable e){
        // Process exception here
    }
}

@BeforeEach
public void makeSureEverythingIsReady(){
    Assumptions.assumeTrue(serviceStarted);
}
```